# Зависает GUI при попытке запустить time.sleep() Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, gui, pyside

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой. Пытаюсь сделать свой будильник с интерфейсом. Самые основные функции он выполняет, но вот когда он уходит в сон ( чтобы через некоторое время зазвонить и уведомить) , интерфейс зависает и нажимать, печатать что-то я не могу. Использую библиотеку PySide, а интерфейс делал в Designer. Слышал я, про многопоточность и `processEvents()`Но я, пока что, не совсем понял что оно такое и если вам не трудно, показывайте примеры или решения на моём коде. Так будет легче, спасибо!

Вот код:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys  #  UI Library
from ui import Ui_Form
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
import time
#
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
#
Form = QtGui.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()
#
def bp():
   entrytime = ui.lineEdit.displayText()
   alarm_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(entrytime, '%H:%M')
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   sleep_time = (alarm_time - now).seconds
   time.sleep(sleep_time) #Здесь проблема
   print("Будильник")
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(bp)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос, на stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194335/4752653. Вкратце - используйте  таймер `QTimer.singleShot` вместо sleep.

Comment: Mihail, нельзя использовать `time.sleep()` в основном потоке.  Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя `time.sleep()` вы замораживаете основной поток, в котором и работает ваше приложение вместе с его графическим интерфейсом. Логично, что ничего не работает, если заморожен поток.
Варианты:

1. (Не советую) Использовать второй поток и запускать time.sleep и что-то там после этого делать. Например `multiprocessing.Process`. Документация: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html
2. Использовать средства библиотеки (`QTimer.singleShot`), в подробностях расписанные в этом вопросе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194335/4752653

Comment: Осталось только пояснить - какая связь между `GUI` и основным потоком.

Comment: Например в tkinter основной поток перехватывается интерпретатором Tc, PySide не знаю

Comment: `GUI` обычно везде работает строго в основном потоке. Это где-то на уровне ОС вообще зашито. Просто это нужно было пояснить в ответе, на мой взгляд.

Comment: А, я думал вы в этом утверждении сомневаетесь. Я тоже когда то time.sleep по глупости в gui использовал

Comment: Исправил, думаю там норм